# How to pass reactive values between observers?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, observers

In the code posted at the bottom, I'm trying to cap the value of the second reactive object (`y`) at the value of the first reactive object (`x`) using two `observeEvents()` as action button click counters, as explained in the illustration below. The illustration shows the results of clicking the "Pos" button 3 times and the "Neg" button 4 times. How would this be done?

I commented-out one of my attempts in the below code.

Illustration:[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <-  fluidPage(br(),
  actionButton("Btn1", "Pos"),
  actionButton("Btn2", "Neg"),
  br(),br(),
  textOutput("posClicks"),
  textOutput("negClicks"),
  textOutput("netClicks")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  x = reactiveVal(0)
  y = reactiveVal(0)
  
  observeEvent(input$Btn1,{x(x()+1)})
  observeEvent(input$Btn2,{y(y()+1)})
  
  # below is commented-out because it gives strange results counting in leaps of 2's
  # observeEvent(input$Btn2,{
  #   if(x()-y(y()+1) >= 0){y(y()+1)}
  #   })
  
  output$posClicks <- renderText({paste('Pos clicks =',x())})
  output$negClicks <- renderText({paste('Neg clicks =',y())})
  output$netClicks <- renderText({paste('Net clicks =',x()-y())})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to have two separate observes, you could do

```
  observeEvent(input$Btn1,{x(x()+1)})
  observeEvent(input$Btn2,{y(y()+1)})
  observe({
     if (y()>x()) {y(x())}
  })
```

Rather than listening for clicks on the button, you just observe the value of `y()` and if it gets bigger than `x()`, just reset it. If you can, it would be easier just to change the Btn2 logic

```
  observeEvent(input$Btn1,{x(x()+1)})
  observeEvent(input$Btn2,{y(min(y()+1, x()))})
```